math angle degrees problem in geometry nodes
(and Merry Christmas wishes)
I don't understand the trigonometric function in geometry nodes.
I tried to translate an object by a 12° in y, so the translation of z must result as sine(12°)*y
I tried with radians. I tried with radians and "to degrees". I tried with gradient.
Nothing goes well

I found the solution: sine(slope)*y = sine(tan(angle))*y
